# Notepad++ v8.5.4 Replace not working for these strings

Tags: notepad++

I am working with lines like this

```
[6268:1434][2023-07-17T03:44:08]i001: Burn v3.14.0.4118, Windows v10.0 (Build 22631: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\{95942D14-E274-486C-A7FB-EDAF9E773422}\.cr\winsdksetup.exe

[6268:1434][2023-07-17T03:44:08]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=E:\Downloads\winsdksetup.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=728 -burn.filehandle.self=740'
```

For search I use

```
    "(.*)2023-07-17(.*): "
```

The Double Quotes just show the string being used and with Regular Expression selected.
That works.

If I then want to replace that with two blank characters.

Should be

```
Burn v3.14.0.4118, Windows v10.0 (Build 22631: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\{95942D14-E274-486C-A7FB-EDAF9E773422}\.cr\winsdksetup.exe
```

getting

```
C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\{95942D14-E274-486C-A7FB-EDAF9E773422}\.cr\winsdksetup.exe
```

Should be

```
Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=E:\Downloads\winsdksetup.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=728 -burn.filehandle.self=740'
```

getting

```
'-burn.clean.room=E:\Downloads\winsdksetup.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=728 -burn.filehandle.self=740'
```

Why is the first ": " not being used as the search delimiter instead of the Last?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. You talk about using a regex to search but then complain that using it in the context of a search&replace operation doesn't yield the desired result without explaining how you're doing the replace. Also, while I understand that Notepad++ is much more powerful than the original Notepad app I would recommend using a different editor like ViM or a full-fledged IDE like VisualStudio.

Comment: What was the "Comment Please" part of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the first ": " not being used as the search delimiter instead
> of the Last?

That is because the `.*` regex matches the longest sequence that allows the rest of the regex to match. That is, `.*` is "greedy" by default. You have two options:

1. Switch to a non-greedy match: `.*?`. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html.
2. Change the second `.*` to match the maximal number of non-colon characters: `[^:]*`.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?2023-07-17.\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\][^:]+:`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
.+?             # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
2023-07-17      # literally
.               # 1 any character
\d\d:\d\d:\d\d  # 2 digits, colon, 2 digits, colon, 2 digit
\]              # ] character
[^:]+           # 1 or more any character that is not a colon
:               # colon and sapce
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]